# Altering a Django model values based on a few conditionals? What is the best practice way to do this?

Tags: django

I have the model `SyncCollector` that has the field `status`. `status` is one of `statusIntervalEnum`. I want to change the existing ones that are `statusIntervalEnum.DYNAMIC` to '`statusIntervalEnum.STATIC.` Now I know that I can do a `SyncCollector.objects.filter(status=statusIntervalEnum.DYNAMIC)` and loop through all of them and save them and perhaps trigger it through a custom endpoint that I later take away, but what is the best way to do this for a production instance?

Making a fake endpoint that I just call in prod to run this seems very hacky.

Comment: Is this something that will need to be triggered multiple times or is this just a one off?

Comment: Note: Although I guess this is not what you want to ask, you don't need to loop over the queryset: `SyncCollector.objects.filter(status=statusIntervalEnum.DYNAMIC).update(status=statusIntervalEnum.STATIC)` should do that. Coming to your question, do you not have access to the database? If this is a one off (and you have access to the database) why not just run a query from the shell?

Comment: @IainShelvington Just a one off. A feature is being changed and new users of the feature will use the STATIC one, but we need the older users transitioned to STATIC from DYNAMIC>

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Can I use the shell to run changes on Django models?

Comment: If a new feature is being introduced it would be better to have a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).